# How to get Formee legend border to grow with DOM elements added programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, web-applications

So I have an application where a user should be able to add an indeterminate number of paired text boxes representing the name and phone number of a person to be submitted to a database. The relevant markup is below...

```
<div id="divAddVoters">
            <form class="formee" action="">
                <fieldset id="appendVoters">
                    <legend>Enter Voter Name and Phone Number:</legend>
                    <!--<div id="appendVoters">-->
                        <div class="grid-4-12" id="appendVoterName">
                            <label>Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="txtAddVoter" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-4-12" id="appendVoterNumber">
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="txtAddNumber" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-4-12"></div>
                    <!--</div>-->
                    <div class="grid-12-12">
                        <button id="btnAddVoter" class="formee-button" 
                                onclick="addVoter(); return false;">ADD VOTER</button>
                        <button id="btnSubmitVoters" class="formee-button" 
                                onclick="submitVoters(); return false;">SUBMIT VOTER(S)</button>
                        <p id="pError"></p>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

...so if the user selects the `btnAddVoter` button any number of times, any number of `txtAddVoter` text boxes should be added to div `appendVoterName` and `txtAddNumber` text boxes should be added to div `appendVoterNumber`. The javascript function to do this is below...

```
function addVoter()
            {
                $('fieldset#appendVoters div#appendVoterName').append("<label>Name</label><input type='text'" +  
                                "class='txtAddVoter' value='' />");

                $('fieldset#appendVoters div#appendVoterNumber').append("<label>Phone Number</label>" +
                                "<input type='text' class='txtAddNumber' value='' />");
            }
```

I'm using `Formee` to make everything look nice, which explains the `fieldset`, `legend` and `form class="formee"` (my application is actually entirely `javascript` driven, so I don't need a form at all except that `formee` styles demand it). The problem is that the border drawn by the legend tag does not grow with the elements added inside of it, so as a user adds textboxes the eventually they overrun the bounds of the legend, over the buttons, and the whole thing looks completely ridiculous.

I'm wondering what the best way to make the legend border grow with the number of contained textbox elements would be. I was thinking about maintaining a count of textboxes, and when they reach a certain number using javascript/jQuery to alter the Formee style sheet to make the legend larger? Not quite sure how to go about this, though, looking for some good ideas.

EDIT - Ok, here's the relevant portion of CSS...

```
.formee fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    position: relative;
    height:30%;
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    margin: 0 0 4em;
}
```

What I want to do is, every time the user adds a textbox pair, read out the height attribute value, double that value, and then set this value as the new height in this CSS rule. Is this possible?

EDIT - I ended up making it happen with this function...

```
    function doubleFieldSetSize(divName)
    {
        var height = $('fieldset#' + divName).css('height');
        height = height.replace(/px$/, '');
        height = parseInt(height) + 70;
        height = height + "px";
        $('fieldset#' + divName).css('height', height);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css, float and height?

```
.formee fieldset {
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    position: relative;    
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    margin: 0 0 4em;
}
```